# for each loop that generates my datagridview/datatable?

Tags: c#, json, datatable, datagridview

I have been scratching my head at this for days now, can't seem to figure it out, no matter how many examples I try to follow it seems like they all stop short of where I get stuck.

I  have a .json file that I `deserialize` into a class(`Datum ToolData`) built by quicktype.io
i then bind that `datasource` to my `datagridview(toolDataGridView)`

at this point it seems every example think its a walk in the park, and should populate my `datagridview` in a matter of a few clicks, and that could be. Just not so easy for me to figure it out.

My only goal at this point is to just display this data in a excel like manner. I originally had this info displayed via an excel file that used PowerQuery to get the data into excel, but it took several minutes just to load the data in. I was happy with getting that far but I want to keep learning and get this to work. I know it can't be much more to get to where I'm trying to get.

Here is the code that handles all the binding and deserializing, I believe after the binding, I need to do some sort of `foreach` loop that would actually populate the `gridview`, but I also have this feeling that I have something setup wrong and that this `gridview` should just populate at this point. The `foreach` loop at the end of this bit of code is not workable for some reason that I dont understand yet. but again, I might not even need it?

**Code**

```
        var loadscreen = new SplashScreen();
        loadscreen.Show();
        string myDynamicJSON = File.ReadAllText(@"testLibrary.json");


        DataGridView ToolDataGridView = new DataGridView();
        DataTable Tool = new DataTable();


        Datum ToolData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Datum>(myDynamicJSON);

        BindingSource SBind = new BindingSource();
        SBind.DataSource = Tool;

        toolDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        toolDataGridView.DataSource = Tool;

        toolDataGridView.DataSource = SBind;

        foreach (string Description in ToolData)
        {

        }
```

Below will be the class that I referenced earlier in this question.

**Code**

```
namespace QuickType
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;


public partial class TestLibrary
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Datum[] Data { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("version")]
    public long Version { get; set; }
}

public partial class Datum
{
    [JsonProperty("BMC")]
    public Bmc Bmc { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty("GRADE", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    //public Grade? Grade { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("geometry")]
    public Geometry Geometry { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("guid")]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty("holder", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    //public Holder Holder { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("post-process")]
    public PostProcess PostProcess { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("product-id")]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("product-link")]
    public string ProductLink { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("start-values")]
    public StartValues StartValues { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("unit")]
    public Unit Unit { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("vendor")]
    public string Vendor { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty("last_modified", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    //public long? LastModified { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty("reference_guid", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    //public string ReferenceGuid { get; set; }
}
}
```

and finally a snippet of my .json file I am deserializing:

****Code****

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "BMC": "carbide",
        "GRADE": "Mill Generic",
        "description": "5/8-11\"",
        "geometry": {
            "CSP": false,
            "DC": 0.433,
            "HAND": true,
            "LB": 2,
            "LCF": 0.5,
            "NOF": 4,
            "NT": 1,
            "OAL": 5,
            "SFDM": 0.625,
            "TP": 0.0909091,
            "shoulder-length": 1.969,
            "thread-profile-angle": 60
        },
        "guid": "0112c196-8a79-421d-8dda-d4aa964aa6d7",
        "holder": {
            "description": "Maritool CAT40-ER32-2.35",
            "guid": "e800051b-e2d6-4699-a2b6-dad6466a0a0c",
            "last_modified": 1485790626152,
            "product-id": "CAT40-ER32-2.35",
            "product-link": "",
            "segments": [
                {
                    "height": 0.148,
                    "lower-diameter": 1.5,
                    "upper-diameter": 1.97
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.836,
                    "lower-diameter": 1.97,
                    "upper-diameter": 1.97
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.176,
                    "lower-diameter": 1.57,
                    "upper-diameter": 1.57
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.09,
                    "lower-diameter": 1.57,
                    "upper-diameter": 1.75
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.425,
                    "lower-diameter": 1.75,
                    "upper-diameter": 1.75
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.05,
                    "lower-diameter": 1.75,
                    "upper-diameter": 1.85
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.03,
                    "lower-diameter": 2.442,
                    "upper-diameter": 2.502
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.145,
                    "lower-diameter": 2.502,
                    "upper-diameter": 2.502
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.079,
                    "lower-diameter": 2.502,
                    "upper-diameter": 2.215
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.118,
                    "lower-diameter": 2.215,
                    "upper-diameter": 2.215
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.079,
                    "lower-diameter": 2.215,
                    "upper-diameter": 2.502
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.143,
                    "lower-diameter": 2.502,
                    "upper-diameter": 2.502
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.03,
                    "lower-diameter": 2.502,
                    "upper-diameter": 2.442
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.125,
                    "lower-diameter": 1.75,
                    "upper-diameter": 1.75
                }
            ],
            "type": "holder",
            "unit": "inches",
            "vendor": "Maritool"
        },
        "post-process": {
            "break-control": false,
            "comment": "",
            "diameter-offset": 17,
            "length-offset": 17,
            "live": true,
            "manual-tool-change": false,
            "number": 17,
            "turret": 0
        },
        "product-id": "GMDTTM58-11UN4FL",
        "product-link": "6010",
        "start-values": {
            "presets": [
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "f_n": 0.012242786571039,
                    "f_z": 0.0031,
                    "guid": "eac33213-4083-35b8-afe3-17bd42a249f0",
                    "n": 4410.76054758139,
                    "n_ramp": 44110,
                    "name": "1018",
                    "tool-coolant": "flood",
                    "use-stepdown": false,
                    "use-stepover": false,
                    "v_c": 499.9999999999994,
                    "v_f": 54.6934307900093,
                    "v_f_leadIn": 54,
                    "v_f_leadOut": 54,
                    "v_f_plunge": 54,
                    "v_f_ramp": 54
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "f_n": 0.010769117817118,
                    "f_z": 0.0028,
                    "guid": "f35f5601-68a9-477b-b4b0-2ffeedb3bef1",
                    "n": 1764.3042190325598,
                    "n_ramp": 1764,
                    "name": "4140",
                    "tool-coolant": "flood",
                    "use-stepdown": false,
                    "use-stepover": false,
                    "v_c": 200,
                    "v_f": 19.7602072531647,
                    "v_f_leadIn": 19,
                    "v_f_leadOut": 19,
                    "v_f_plunge": 19,
                    "v_f_ramp": 19
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "f_n": 0.012091641057817,
                    "f_z": 0.0031,
                    "guid": "b118ce46-da35-4ed6-9806-b98e05ffe077",
                    "n": 2646.45632854884,
                    "n_ramp": 2646,
                    "name": "Tool Steel",
                    "tool-coolant": "flood",
                    "use-stepdown": false,
                    "use-stepover": false,
                    "v_c": 300,
                    "v_f": 32.8160584740056,
                    "v_f_leadIn": 32,
                    "v_f_leadOut": 32,
                    "v_f_plunge": 32,
                    "v_f_ramp": 32
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "f_n": 0.01118476797848,
                    "f_z": 0.0028,
                    "guid": "0e1767f5-b0ef-422f-b49d-6cb8c3eb06ed",
                    "n": 3308.0704106860494,
                    "n_ramp": 3308,
                    "name": "Stainless Steel",
                    "tool-coolant": "flood",
                    "use-stepdown": false,
                    "use-stepover": false,
                    "v_c": 375,
                    "v_f": 37.0503885996837,
                    "v_f_leadIn": 37,
                    "v_f_leadOut": 37,
                    "v_f_plunge": 37,
                    "v_f_ramp": 37
                }
            ]
        },
        "type": "thread mill",
        "unit": "inches",
        "vendor": "Gorilla Mill"
    },
```

Here is dataset in picture to show columns
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `DataTable` but never filling it with anything. Then you are binding this to the `DataGridView`, also, you set the `DataSource` multiple times, overwriting the previous value:

```
    //So you have an empty DataTable object
    DataTable Tool = new DataTable();

    //You got the data
    Datum ToolData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Datum>(myDynamicJSON);
    //You create a new BindingSource
    BindingSource SBind = new BindingSource();
    //You just set this to an empty DataTable
    SBind.DataSource = Tool;

    toolDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

    //What is the point of this? As you set it again in the next line?
    toolDataGridView.DataSource = Tool;

    toolDataGridView.DataSource = SBind;
```

I think what you want to do, is populate the `DataTable` before doing any binding, so you'd do:

```
//You got the data
Datum ToolData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Datum>(myDynamicJSON);

//So you have an empty DataTable object
DataTable Tool = new DataTable();

//add columns
Tool.Columns.Add("somecolumnname");
//etc..until done adding columns

foreach (string Description in ToolData.{someProperty})
{
    //Populate the DataTable with rows of data
    DataRow dr = Tool.NewRow();
    // Fill the values
    dr["somecolumnname"] = Description;
    //maybe some other column values...
    
    Tool.Rows.Add(dr);
}

//Now you have a DataTable with something in it, do the binding:
BindingSource SBind = new BindingSource();
SBind.DataSource = Tool;
toolDataGridView.DataSource = SBind;
```

Comment: the foreach line throws an error right now,  would this go away if the datatable has data in it? also i would need a new foreach for every column correct?
Error CS1579 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Datum' because 'Datum' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: now i have 2 errors, the one from before, plus another sayingthat DataTable does not contain definition for AddColumn. for what its worth, my datatable inside of a dataset already has columns so i dont think i need to add them here correct? i left that bit out..

Comment: @JoeFisher That's my bad. You can only run a `foreach` on an `IEnumerable`, so as I am unsure of what you are trying to iterate in your deserialized object, you'd replace `ToolData` with `ToolData.{SomeIEnumerableProperty}` also, it's `Tool.Columns.Add`, not `Tool.AddColumn`, I was in a hurry and mistyped. see updated answer.

Comment: so i changed my foreach to the following, foreach (string Description in ToolData.Description), but now i get cannot convert type char to string. im diving into it but is it as simple as changing the type of tooldata.description in my dataset designer?

Comment: @JoeFisher `ToolData.Description` is a string, iterating it produces each individual `char`, that's why it's complaining. What are your column names and what do you want to populate each row with in your `foreach`?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of my columns in the datatable at the bottom of my main post. the .json file has misc data in it for all these fields. almost all of them can be strings. im not really doing too much with this data other than displaying it and searching for it later on. basically just an inventory. i will manually ad a few columns that i will do simple addition and subtraction to as well.